# A float that 0.0 equals one transform position and 100.0 equals another transform postion

Tags: c#

I have a Healthbar with a mask over it.

I need a fluid change on the Y axis.

The position for 100% is -185.6 while the position for 0% is -78.6, I want to be able to have a float where 0.0 is -78.6 and 100.0 is -185.6 and whenever the float is changed to something in between 0 and 100 it is changed to the corresponding value in-between -185.6 and -78.6.

Comment: You are talking about linear scaling?

Comment: Dude.  **R T F M**  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide a linear scale between any two particular values.

```
float scale(float percent) {
  float min = -185.6;
  float max = -78.6;
  return min + ((max-min)*percent);
}
```

A more general approach would be

```
float scale(float a, float b, float p) {
  return Math.min(a, b) + Math.abs(a - b) * p;
}
```

Doesn't you can just pass in any two values and get a value some % between them. Doesn't assume a is less than b.

Comment: Hi Colin, FWIW the OP was asking about the game engine  Unity.  You just use `Lerp`.